# Google geocoding API don't recognize french amusement parks

Tags: google-geocoding-api

All is in the title, why the google-geocoding-api don't recognize french amusement parks ?
Example request for "Parc Asterix" :

- [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=parc+asterix&components=country:fr](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=parc%20asterix&components=country:fr)

Here, the result for ["parc asterix" in google maps](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Parc+Ast%C3%A9rix/@49.1341874,2.5690414,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47e671ae444f41bb:0x95cf289d71bcfb42).

Thanks for your help

Comment: I see a json with some geo information on the first link.  But am not by a computer to confirm where the long/lat lands. The 2nd link opens up google maps and pin points the parq.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in the JSON there is no information about the park. It's just recognize FRANCE.